# How to mask a group?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, clipping-mask

I have a bunch of groups and I want to mask them using a shape.
Is there any way to do that?

[image: Clip]

(Without having to rasterize or unwrap the layers)

Comment: Edited a little. "clipping" is a specific thing in Photoshop.... it appears you want "masking" not "clipping".

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select the shapes you want to use as a mask.
- Copy them with <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (or cut them with <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> if you don't need them for anything else).
- Select the group.
- Paste with <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and the shapes will become a vector mask on the selected group.

[image]

Comment: That's it. At first I couldn't cut the layer nor paste it as a layer mask. First I had to select the shape via `Ctrl / Cmd` + `Click` as you did.

Comment: Btw, which screen recorder did you use?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I wrote "Select the *shapes*" instead of "select the shape *layer*" - maybe it's not clear enough?

Comment: I'm using [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) for Windows.

Comment: Well, I knew that I had to select the shapes, but I forgot that I had to press `Ctrl`...
Btw, I'm the creator of that tool. Nice!

Comment: Wow, I love ScreenToGif! I use it all the time for answers to this site and to help clients. Thanks for giving it away for free.